# Использование символа "_" в качестве промежуточной переменной для цикла

Tags: python

У меня появился вопрос почему некоторые разрабы на python, используют этот символ в качестве промежуточной переменной в цикле:

```
for _ in items:
    print(_)
```

может это традиционно как то в python так писать?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

В вашем примере символ подчеркивания использовать как раз не надо. В циклах он используется, чтобы показать, что эта переменная не применяется в вычислениях и не имеет никакого значения.

```
for _ in range(5):
    print("Hohoho!")
```

Еще в переменной `_` хранится значение последнего выражения в интерпретаторе:

```
>>> 3*2
6
>>> _
6
>>>
```

Comment: Спасибо за ответ! Уяснил)))

Answer (score 3):

Есть неписанное соглашение использовать подчеркивание (`_`) в качестве имени переменной если нужно использовать переменную, но ее не будут использовать.

Примеры:

```
def f(x):
    print(x)
```

если запустить:

```
In [47]: [f(x) for x in list("abc")]
a
b
c
Out[47]: [None, None, None]
```

вернется список None, чтобы этого избежать можно использовать:

```
In [48]: _ = [f(x) for x in list("abc")]
a
b
c
```

---

Кроме этого Python Interpreter по умолчанию сохраняет результат последнего выражения в переменной `_`:

```
>>> 10**2
100
>>> print(_)
100
>>>
```

---

кроме этого подчеркивание можно использовать для визуального разделения в числах:

```
In [51]: 123_456_789
Out[51]: 123456789

In [52]: 0b_0110
Out[52]: 6

In [53]: 0x_23_be
Out[53]: 9150
```

Comment: не понял этого момента `если нужно использовать переменную, но ее не будут использовать`

Answer (score 2):

Вообще, тема с подчеркиванием в питоне холиворная. Вставлю свои две копейки: хотя подчеркивание и не является спецсимволом в питоне и его можно использовать для наименования переменной, функции, класса и даже модуля, я бы не рекомендовал так делать. В питоне есть пакет [`gettext`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/gettext.html), который используется для локализации программ. Этот пакет при инсталляции локализаций прописывает алиас подчеркивания на `gettext.gettext`, ведь проще помечать текст на локализацию так:

```
print(_('Hello there!'))
```

чем так:

```
print(gettext.gettext('Hello there!'))
```

Поэтому проблема с подчеркиванием в том, что оно может переписать алиас локализации, и если не повезет и в переменной сохранится функция с совместимой сигнатурой, можно долго искать ответ на вопрос, почему вдруг сломалась локализация. В большинстве случаев просто на ровном месте работавший раньше код начинает кидать исключения а-ля `str is not callable`, это может быть сигналом того, что кто-то переназначил андерскор.

Так что использовать или не использовать `_`, каждый решает сам; если код не локализовывать или в команде принята своя конвенция (к примеру, алиасить `gettext` на `loc` вместо `_`), то ничего страшного в андерскоре нет. У нас большинство проектов на питоне так или иначе связаны с Django, так что пользуемся его стилем и присвоение подчеркивания отлавливаем линтером при коммитах и в CI до старта тестов.